# SQL add constraint if enum then column is not nullable

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, sum

Given a schema

```
CREATE TYPE offer AS ENUM ('DISCOUNT', 'COUPON');

CREATE TABLE voucher (
...
offerType offer NOT NULL,
couponCode text
)
```

Is there a way to add a constraint to voucher that if offer type is COUPON then couponCode is not nullable and if offer type is DISCOUNT then couponCode has to be null?

Comment: check ((offerType = 'COUPON' and couponCode  is not null) or (offerType = 'DISCOUNT' and couponCode  is null) or (offerType not in ( 'COUPON', 'DISCOUNT')))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check ((offerType = 'COUPON' and couponCode is not null) or
       (offerType = 'DISCOUNT' and couponCode is null) or
       (offerType not in ( 'COUPON', 'DISCOUNT'))
      )
```

The `(offerType not in ( 'COUPON', 'DISCOUNT'))` part is needed of other offertypes are inserted later.